# BJT Cascade Difference Amplifier Exercise

Tags: amplifier, diodes, bjt, zener

I need help with the exercise. The questions:

1. Add or Design Components to have a current source I=2 mA at the picture.
2. Draw equivalent small signal,low frequency model.
3. Find Ai, Zo, Zi.

If possible,could anyone also explain to me the roles of Zener and Q3, VEE, and also the Q4,Q5, what do they do in the circuit?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> the roles of Zener and Q3, VEE

this is a [constant current source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source#Zener_diode_current_source). It is used to polarize the differential amplifier, while providing a high impedance in the emitter, which notably improves the CMRR

> Q3,Q4, what do they do in the circuit

I guess you mean Q4 and Q5. These transistors form the second stage of the differential amplifier, connected in cascade with the first stage.

> Add or Design Components to have a current source I=2 mA at the picture.

I guess you mean the current source for Q4 and Q5. There are many possibilities for this case, the most common is to use a [current mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_mirror).

> Find Ai,Zo,Zi.

This goes beyond the scope of the answer, just point out that you must use the [small signal models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-signal_model) for each active element and apply the [network analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_analysis_(electrical_circuits)), looking for the requested relationships.

I hope this answer is helpful to complete your homework.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. So that's why my professor hinted us to use Zener and BJT as constant current source for Q4 and Q5, which I didn't understand at the time. I'm still stuck at the equivalent small signal model though,haha. Your answers simplify a lot for me though.

Comment: @LinhTrầnQuang In that case, first review all the content about the model for small signal and impedance reflection, since without that information it will be impossible to obtain the gain and impedance parameters.

Comment: Well my course is mainly about Circuit Analysis so I've already known about small signal model and impedance reflection, it's just the homework is usually 10 times harder (or so my prof told us) than what we learn in class. The example is a simple Cascade Difference Amplifier, only has Q1,Q2,Re .Somehow the homework has a lot more components,Q3,4,5,6;Re is replaced with Q3 and Zener.

Comment: I've finished my homework,thanks y'all